# Should generated css files be located together with my component's source code?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have followed to official guide to add `node-sass` as a css pre-processor:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc

The generated `css` files are put with my source code.

```
Component
--Component.css
--Component.scss
--Component.tsx
```

I dislike this for two reasons:

- It clutters up the file explorer
- As the `css` files are generated I don't consider them as part of the source code but rather part of the build

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Or are more people moving their css files out of their source folder?

Comment: Do you have any other processor at your project, like npm scripts, gulp or grunt? It's possible to combine all css, minify it and store in something like a 'dist/build' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, generated code should not be included in your git repository. This is to avoid messy merge conflicts and using outdated generated files.

I normally create a 'target' folder and output all generated files to this folder. The naming convention to this folder is up to you. Some people like to use 'dist'. I then add this folder to my .gitignore file.